# MITM or Something Else?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, openssl

**Problem:**

When a given set of user devices (tablets/laptops) downloads files from a certain server from outside the host server's country, downloads are sporadically and routinely interrupted. The cause is unknown.

If the downloads were to occur domestically within the host server's country, no problems would be experienced, regardless of distance.

This behavior occurs using any download method, including browsers such as Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

WGET produces some more information on the error as follows:

```
Read error at byte 139935417/324659120 (A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.). Retrying.
```

(WGET then reconnects and finishes the download. These interruptions occur multiple times during a download.)

To rule out any concerns about connection reliability, it can be confirmed the connections are considered stable and reliable.

**Question:**

What could be causing this error, and, could these errors be failed MITM attempts?

Comment: How are you confirming that the connections are "highly reliable"?

Comment: Yes. Connections are reliable.

Comment: Sorry. The first word of my comment was supposed to be "How"... It's fixed now.

Comment: We first ruled out the server connection itself by downloading domestically. Worked perfectly with a 100% success rate. We then downloaded from other servers outside the host server's country, domestic to the location of the device, and there too we had a 100% success rate. We experience no other problems connection wise. Some connections to other servers have been up for many weeks without interruption in fact. In sum, everything else works just fine.

Comment: So S1 to C1 works, and S2 to C2 works. There still could be a connection issue between S1 and C2. Could simply be a bad or misconfigured router/switch/etc.

Comment: Or an MITM attempt...

Comment: There is something in the middle (router/switch/firewall/server) that is causing an issue, likely due to a fault in hardware/software or due to a misconfiguration. If the *thing* in the middle is trying to unlawfully inspect your data, then you could call it a MITM attack, but even a MITM attack should be undetectable if it's working properly. In other words, a connection problem and a MITM attack really should have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: If the connections were reliable, the downloads would work.

Comment: Without more information, we cannot solve this problem.

Comment: If you can provide more information, I think that this is more appropriate for https://superuser.com as it seems a straight network problem and, despite your assurances otherwise, not a security problem.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the location of the server in relation to the location of the client, there is a high probability it is indeed a malicious attack of some unknown type. Perhaps not MITM, but something which does illicitly interrupt the connection. The attack could be considered sophisticated because it occurs randomly on an active TLS connection. (Random to the user, on command to the attacker).

Neither the server nor the client are within the possession of the attacker, and the attacker is yet able to interrupt an active international TLS connection at will. Serious stuff. If it is verified to be an attack, state sponsored actors are likely the culprit.

This type of attack is documented in CVE-2014-3466 for GNUTLS as a memory corruption attack, termed the 'Hello Vulnerability'. A bug report or security report should be submitted to *bugs AT gnutls.org* so that this issue can be studied.

Further information on this vulnerability can be found here:

http://radare.today/posts/technical-analysis-of-the-gnutls-hello-vulnerability/

-and-

http://gnutls.org/security.html

Comment: CVE-2014-3466  deals with ServerHello, which happens at the beginning of the connection. It does not explain why the problems happens in the middle of the connection. I would rather say it is some faulty router in between which corrupts packets from time to time.